# C#: find HTML attribute and replace value using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: html, dom, html-agility-pack

Hi I am experimenting how to use HTMLAgilityPack Vs using Regex (Not sure which is more Expensive). My question id with HTMLAgilityPack I am able to extract the required attribute and replace it with a new one; however, I cant seems to update the original text. Here is the code;

```
string input = @"<area shape=""rect"" coords=""0,0,82,126"" href=""one"" alt=""Sun""> <area shape=""rect"" coords=""0,0,82,126"" href=""two"" alt=""Sun"" > <area shape=""rect"" coords=""0,0,82,126"" href=""Three"" alt=""Sun"" >";

HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(input);

HtmlNodeCollection nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//area");

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++ )
{
    HtmlNode node = nodes[i];
    var href = node.Attributes["href"].Value;
    //Reassigning href value
    node.Attributes["href"].Value="Re-Assign ["+i+"]";
}
```

Now I want to make this reflect in the original "input" variable. Any idea how to proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am also experimenting with how to use the Agility Pack. Try with:

```
String HTML = nodes.DocumentNode.WriteTo();
```

you need to write the updates in the original text.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `doc.Save(yourFileName);`